# Xcode Memory Editor

Tags: xcode

When I open the Memory Editor in Xcode at a breakpoint, any address I go to shows this:[image]

However, the answer to this question has actual readable numbers and letters in the Memory Editor: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748866/how-to-print-the-contents-of-a-memory-address-using-lldb). Why am I seeing this instead of letters and numbers?

Comment: What I mean is, when I searched up what the memory editor is supposed to look like, I saw that there was letters and numbers showing up. I understand what memory is, but I don't understand how it is being represented.

Comment: For example, the answer to this question has actual readable numbers and letters in the memory browser. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748866/how-to-print-the-contents-of-a-memory-address-using-lldb/22013204#22013204)

Comment: Oh. Well that's what it looks like on my machine too. I don't know why your screenshot is gibberish.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? What machine / code / actions do I need, to see what you're seeing?

Comment: You have to open the memory browser, by doing Command + Option + Control + Shift + M, than put in any memory address in the address slot, which will pull up what I am seeing.

Comment: Well that's not how you use it. You debug a project, pause at a breakpoint, select an object in the variables list of the debugger pane, and choose "View Memory Of..." that object.

Comment: You can use it that way, I'm just saying any memory address will cause this. And you can't even pull up the Memory Editor unless you hit a breakpoint. I know how to use the editor, what I'm asking is, why don't I see the hexadecimal values? Why am I seeing this weird gibberish?

Comment: I don't know why. I've described what I did that works. I don't know how to get the gibberish on my machine. But you can't just stick a random memory value in. I've explained what to do, do you get gibberish if you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't "pull up" the memory editor. You inspect the memory of a particular object. You debug a project, pause at a breakpoint, select an object in the variables list of the debugger pane, and choose "View Memory Of..." that object.