# Viewing the memory (bytes) from an address onwards in Xcode

Tags: xcode

In visual studio I can set a breakpoint in my code and, when execution breaks, get the address of the memory I am interested in, and then put the address into the memory window to see all the memory bytes from the address onwards. Here's an example:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 screenshot]

You can see the breakpoint hit in the middle Visual Studio window, the watch on the variable I am interested in in the bottom window that gives me the address, and I typed the address into the top window to see the memory there.

After execution hits a breakpoint in Xcode how do I view the bytes in memory from a particular address onwards?

(N.B. I have tried to search online for this but my search results are dominated by Xcode's memory usage monitor, which is not what I am after.)

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22013204/1187415.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print memory in 0xb0987654 using lldb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748866/how-to-print-memory-in-0xb0987654-using-lldb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I open the memory browser in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052402/how-do-i-open-the-memory-browser-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) points out in his comment on my question, Eric covers exactly this in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22013204/575530) to the question [How to print memory in 0xb0987654 using lldb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19748866/575530). Eric explains that Xcode has a **Memory Browser** window that displays the contents of a given memory addresses.

[image: Eric's screenshot of Swift's memory browser]

Eric mentions that we can access the memory browser by pressing **⌘⌥⇧M** or through the **Debug --> Debug Workflow --> View Memory** menus.

He notes that there is a field in its bottom left corner where we can paste the memory address you want to inspect.

Lastly he provides a link to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/viewing_memory.html) and to another [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053116/575530)

Comment: Is there a way to refresh the memory view from LLDB?